# Tingling sensation when MacBook Air M1 is getting charged

Tags: macbook-pro

When charging my MacBook M1, it feels like there's electricity, there's a tingling sensation, why does this happen? Can someone authorized answer?What is the reason for this?

Comment: To summarize: yes, it's normal and safe. Using the longer cable from the power brick to the wall (which you now have to buy separately) to ground the machine.
https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MK122B/A/power-adapter-extension-cable